# React DnD / TypeScript: How to use getDropResult?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-dnd

In my React web app, I have a number of [`react-dnd`](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd) drop targets:

```js
const DropTarget = () => {
  const [{ canDrop, isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: 'MyDnDItemType',
    drop: () => ({ name: 'name of this drop target' })
  }))
   ...
}
```

and items to drag around and drop in those targets:

```js
const DraggableItem = () => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    type: 'MyDnDItemType'
  })
   ...
```

When a `DraggableItem` is dropped into one of the `DropTarget`s, I would like to get the drop target `name`. The `react-dnd` [`useDrag` docs](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drag) say in the `end(item, monitor)` section:

> If [...] the drop target specified a drop result by returning a plain object from its `drop()` method, it will be available as `monitor.getDropResult()`.

However, when I add an `end(...)` function in `useDrag(...)` and attempt to access the plain object returned, I get a TypeScript compiler error `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`.

```js
const DraggableItem = () => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    end: (item, monitor) => {
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
      // console.log('dropResult:', dropResult)
      // sample log output:
      //   dropResult: {dropEffect: 'move', name: 'name of this drop target'}

      // PROBLEM: this fails to compile with
      //   Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
      console.log('name:', dropResult.name)
    },
    type: 'MyDnDItemType'
  })
   ...
```

I also tried `end: (item, monitor: DragSourceMonitor) ...`  and, after reading about [this somewhat related issue](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/3192) and delving into the [source code](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/main/packages/react-dnd/src/types/monitors.ts#L13), tried to use an explicit type:

```js
type MyType = {
  name: string;
};

const DraggableItem = () => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    end: (item, monitor: DragSourceMonitor<MyType>) => {
     ... (as above) ...
```

but the error persists.

How can I access the plain object returned by `getDropResult()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: Was on the right track, but didn't follow through.

Some quick background info: Until a couple of minutes ago, I knew only *very* little about TypeScript and, as for generics, only what I remember about C++ templates from ~20 years ago; probably close to nothing. It's not that hard, though:

The [`DragSourceMonitor` interface](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/main/packages/react-dnd/src/types/monitors.ts#L13) takes two type parameters `DragObject` and `DropResult`, which per default are `unknown`:

```js
export interface DragSourceMonitor<DragObject = unknown, DropResult = unknown>
```

One of the methods on that interface is [`getDropResult`](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/main/packages/react-dnd/src/types/monitors.ts#L42) which takes a single type parameter `T`, using `DropResult` as default:

```js
getDropResult<T = DropResult>(): T | null
```

This provides two entry points to fix the compiler error:

**Either** use own types to pass to `DragSourceMonitor`, e.g.

```js
type MyDragObject = {
  name: string;
}

type MyDropResult = {
  name: string;
}

const DraggableTreeItem = (props: TreeItemProps) => {

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    }),
   ...
  end: (item, monitor: DragSourceMonitor<MyDragObject, MyDropResult>) => {
   ...
```

**or** pass the type to use only when calling `getDropResult(...)`, e.g.

```js
type MyDropResult = {
  name: string;
}

const DraggableTreeItem = (props: TreeItemProps) => {

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
   ...
  end: (item, monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => {
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult<MyDropResult>()
      // getDropResult returns `T | null`, so need to test
      // against null to fix `Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)`
      if (dropResult) {
        console.log('name:', dropResult.name)
      }
     ...
  }
   ...
```